# Convert string with Year and Month ONLY... to the date format for Year and Month only

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-formatting

Bit of a weird ask, but I have rows and rows of year/months as a string and i'm trying to convert it into date format.

Not too sure this can be done as it's not a full date but worth an ask.

```
UPDATE table
SET [Year Month] = CONVERT (DATE, [Year Month], 103)
```

Returns

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

String of data looks like this:

```
|Year Month|
| 2015-02  |
| 2016-06  |
| 2016-01  |
| 2020-09  |
```

Have seen other posts but they all stem from having the full date already and just essentially cutting of the day to grab the year month etc. but in this case its only year and month that I have as a string and is needed to format into date year and month

Comment: what's the date that you want? `01` or end of month? or something else?

Comment: what version of SQL Server? `select @@version`

Comment: i just want to return the same data above but replace it as a date format instead of string

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64)   Jul  6 2017 07:55:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit)

Comment: @VS1SQL In order to have it as `DATE` it must be a valid date. And the valid date has `day` defined.

Comment: hmm, I was afraid of that, so there is no way to change the above to date format from string. I suppose i could put a 1 at the end and make it a full date and seperate them into their date parts. Not ideal but might be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You need choose a day (here the first of the month) to convert a text field containing a couple `year/month` to a valid date field :

SQL Server (convert an [ISO date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD, YYYYMMDD... to a date):

```
UPDATE table
SET [Year Month Day] = cast([Year Month] + '-01' as DATE )
```

Oracle (you can explicitly choose the format):

```
UPDATE table
SET YearMonthDay = TO_DATE(YearMonth || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEFROMPARTS` starting in SQL Server 2012 but you have to specify the day for it to be a `DATE`

```
--set to first day of month
UPDATE table
SET [Year Month] = DATEFROMPARTS ( LEFT([Year Month], 4), RIGHT([Year Month], 2) , 1 )
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @Year_Month VARCHAR(7) = '2015-02'

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( LEFT(@Year_Month, 4), RIGHT(@Year_Month, 2) , 1 )
```